# Implications of auto incementing the assembly and or file version of Silverlight app?

Tags: silverlight, versioning

Are there implications of auto incrementing the AssemblyVersion or the AssemblyFileVersion of a Silverlight app?  Are those values used by the Silverlight runtime or IIS at some point?

Related to this is the 'version' of the xap's only defined by the aspx page code..such as:

```
<param name="source" value="ClientBin/myApp.xap?ver=1"/>
```

I've seen this on a couple posts but I was unclear as to what exactly is does.

ep

Answer (score 0):

If your web server does not do anything with the query parameter (?ver=1), it won't do anything with Silverlight strictly speaking.

The real use for this additionnal parameter is an astuce to guarantee that the client execute the good version of the application. For the browser, myApp.xap?ver=1 is a different content than myApp.xap?ver=2. Therefore if myApp.xap?ver=1 is in the browser cache but your page uses myApp.xap?ver=2, the browser will download it. If you hadn't added this "useless" query parameter, it wouldn't have... And your client would have seen the old app version until his browser cache refreshes itself.